# Conjecture on the roots of $F_1(n)$

Tags: number-theory, roots, totient-function

Define the following function function
$$F_m(n) = -n + \prod_{p\mid n}\left(p^2-m\right)$$
for $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$. It is connected to the Dedekind psi function and Euler totient function as follows, Let
$$\phi (n) = n\prod_{p\mid n}\left( 1 - \frac{1}{p}\right)$$
$$\psi (n) = n\prod_{p\mid n}\left( 1 + \frac{1}{p}\right)$$
Then
$$\psi (n)\phi (n) = n^2\prod_{p\mid n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)$$
Which is equal to Jordan's totient function $J_2(n)$. We can rearrange to find
$$J_2(n) = \left(\frac{n}{\text{rad}(n)}\right)^2\prod_{p\mid n}\left(p^2-1\right)$$
Which after rearranging leaves us with the special case that
$$F_1(n) = J_2(n)\left(\frac{\text{rad}(n)}{n}\right)^2 - n$$

I'm interested in finding all numbers such that they are a root of $F_1(n)$. An obvious requirement for this is that
$$n = \prod_{p\mid n}p^2-1$$
We can easily see by the right hand side $\prod_{p\mid n}p^2-1$ is independant of the total number of prime factors. If we consider $n = p^{\alpha}$ then we can see
$$p^{\alpha} = p^2-1$$
which does not hold true. Hence we need $n: \omega(n) > 1$, where
$$\omega(n) = \sum_{p\mid n}1$$
For example, for any number of the form $2^{\alpha} \cdot 3^{\beta}$ $\forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{N}$, we get
$$F_1(2^{\alpha} \cdot 3^{\beta})=(2^2-1)(3^2-1) = 24$$
And since $24 = 3 \cdot 2^3$ we get
$$F_1(24) = 0$$

24 seems to be the smallest example. Following the method of increasing in value of prime divisors we can consider the next value to be of the form $2^{\alpha}\cdot 5^{\beta}$.
$$F_1(2^{\alpha}\cdot 5^{\beta}) = 72$$
However $72 = 2^3 \cdot 3^2$ hence there is no $F_1(2^{\alpha}\cdot 5^{\beta}) = 72$. We can also see that there is no $F_1(3^{\alpha}\cdot 5^{\beta})$ as $5^2-1 = 3\cdot 2^3$. The same goes for $7^2-1 = 2(5^2-1) =...$. In fact, I don't know if this is proven or not, but it seems that all $$p^2-1 = 2^{\alpha} \cdot 3^{\beta} \cdot q \,\,\,\text{for some q} \in \mathbb{N}$$

Therefore, I conjecture that 24 is the only root of $F_1(n)$. My question is whether anyone has any ideas, approahes, things they would like to add... etc that you think might be useful, or if anyone has found a value for $n$ that would disprove the conjecture. I'm open to any suggestions too. Many thanks!

Comment: Hint : $n$ cannot have a prime factor greater than $3$ because then the product cannot be divisible by the greatest prime factor of $n$. The rest should be easy. Formally, $1$ is also a root. But that's it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I can change the notation. Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh, everything which is not yet taken like Euler's totient $\phi(n)$ etc. So perhaps $F_m(n)$?

Comment: For $n=1$ , the product is empty (no prime factors) and therefore $1$ , hence $\Phi_1(1)=0$

Comment: @Peter Yes you are correct! My apologies